# Distorted texture on a plane

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I have this pool scene that I am trying to do and I have been trying for 2 hours to fix the distorted texture but cant figure it out. Tried different modelling approaches but nothing helped. I set the subdivision surface modifier to adaptive subdivision because I want to use the displacement of the texture. Tried different UV unwrapping methods but didnt help either but maybe I just did them wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How have you textured and UV unwrapped the floor? I tried to replicate the issue but can't get such distortions.

Comment: Yes. Added a Texture and UV unwrapped with Smart uv, cube projection, project from view (in top view) and even manually